# Not able to start spring boot application using jshell

Tags: java, java-9, java-10, jshell

I am trying to start a spring boot jar executable for my project from jshell but it throws an exception and does not start.

Commands that I am running:

> ./jshell --class-path myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Once jshell starts I invoke:

> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(new String[0])

This throws the following exception which is very short and not much useful I guess:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException thrown
        at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
        at MainMethodRunner.run (MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:87)
        at Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:50)
        at JarLauncher.main (JarLauncher.java:51)
        at (#1:1)
```

After this, I tried to start the main class again and I got the following exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2e571f76]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
    at java.base/java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1184)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:667)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-07-06 16:01:09.422 ERROR 87398 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.openchs.OpenCHS.main(OpenCHS.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
    at REPL.$JShell$12.do_it$($JShell$12.java:4)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.DirectExecutionControl.invoke(DirectExecutionControl.java:209)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.RemoteExecutionControl.invoke(RemoteExecutionControl.java:116)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.DirectExecutionControl.invoke(DirectExecutionControl.java:119)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.ExecutionControlForwarder.processCommand(ExecutionControlForwarder.java:144)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.ExecutionControlForwarder.commandLoop(ExecutionControlForwarder.java:237)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.Util.forwardExecutionControl(Util.java:76)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.Util.forwardExecutionControlAndIO(Util.java:137)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.RemoteExecutionControl.main(RemoteExecutionControl.java:70)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 common frames omitted

|  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException thrown
|        at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
|        at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|        at DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|        at Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
|        at MainMethodRunner.run (MainMethodRunner.java:48)
|        at Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:87)
|        at Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:50)
|        at JarLauncher.main (JarLauncher.java:51)
|        at (#2:1)
```

I am using Gradle as a dependency management tool.

Comment: Why are you starting the app with jshell?

Comment: I am starting the app with jshell so I can change things while the app is running.

Answer (score 3):

Don't start your Spring Boot application using JShell - just use java.

`java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

JShell is for running simple evaluations, not web servers:

> JShell is a Read-Evaluate-Print Loop (REPL), which evaluates declarations, statements, and expressions as they are entered and immediately shows the results. The tool is run from the command line.

Comment: Well, people in other languages do use REPLs for everything. I know that I can just use java but as I said in the answer to comment on the question: I want to change things while the app is running

Comment: It's true you're not going to want to mess with executing a spring boot app from anywhere but the command line, but you could use remote debugging to achieve a lot of what you're looking to do with jshell. 

If you're willing to put a bit more work in to specifying how you interact with the app by creating custom commands, you might want to consider opening a spring shell once the app starts:  

https://projects.spring.io/spring-shell/

I'm currently playing around with this, but the app I'm developing intends to expose a CLI, not just use one for debugging purposes.

Comment: Totally appreciate this @JBKM :)